# Example of a tangent line intersecting with multiplicity three in a smooth point

Tags: abstract-algebra, intersection-theory

In [these notes](http://www.fen.bilkent.edu.tr/~franz/ag05/ag-06.pdf) it is said that a tangent line to a smooth point $p$ of a curve $C$ can be characterised as the unique line $L$ such that $mult( L\cap C,q_0)\geq 2,$ where mult means intersection multiplicity. I was trying to write down an example of such a point with intersection multiplicity precisely three but couldn't manage. For intersection multiplicity four, I took a parabola of degree four and the tangent at the origin.

Can someone provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $x$ axis meets the cubic $y=x^3$ with multiplicity $3$ at the origin. You just have to overcome your prejudice and allow a tangent line to cross the curve.